# how to fix the error in Jupyter notebook which which i see when i try to import any thing

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, algorithm, machine-learning, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to fix this issue since last many days but I dont know whats wrong. The same works on the other PC. Please help.

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-f7d5b693e8f6> in <module>
----> 1 import pandas as pd
      2 import xgboost as xgb
      3 import sklearn.linear_model
      4 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
      5 import sklearn.svm
```

I wish to import the required packages as stated in the error above

Comment: The first error message informs that module "pandas" is can't be found. 
It may be not installed or python interpreter can't find it. 

https://docs.python.org/3.7/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the help this really worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you installed the packages in your current environment?

Shutdown your jupyter instance, and then in the same terminal run:

```
pip3 install pandas xgboost matplotlib sklearn
```

or if you're using conda:

```
conda install pandas xgboost matplotlib sklearn
```

Restart your jupyter instance, and you should be able to load the packages.

If that doesn't work, you're going to need to give more information:

- Operating System
- Python version
- Detailed stack trace.

Comment: i tried doing but this was the error i found. and its since start im getting .                                                          
      
)
Collecting xgboost
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/2e/bd/ad3a963b630fa3ee72d1a672fd207263fa0a18113688273afe8298293535/x
gboost-0.82.tar.gz
Files/directories not found in C:\Users\patel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-u5o2uxag\xgboost\pip-egg-info

Comment: I missed that you were using Python 3.x. Try with pip3. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Also, if you're not using Anaconda, I would recommend it, especially given the types of modules you seem to be using.

Comment: This was really helpful sir. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The error "ModuleNotFoundError Traceback" means one or more of the libraries are missing. Make sure that you have installed all of the libraries.

To debug the problem, try doing an import one by one and identify what is missing.